# well off / Okay / good and How to use placeholder 'it'

Tags: sentence-structure

Here's the context.

> We had been dating for more than a year until we broke up a month ago. I' okay now.
>
> 1. However, the very first few days that I spent alone without her, it (seemed  / was) like something I could never overcome.
> 2. However, the very first few days that I spent alone without her, it seemed almost impossible to get over her and become (well off / okay / good)

Q1. which one is natural among the words in the bracket.

Q2. in the #1, I tried to make 'it' and 'the very fist few days' equal, whereas In the #2, 'it' represents 'to get over~~',did I do well?

Q3. Here we can not remove 'the' from 'the very first few days' because it's definite time, right?

Comment: Carefull: "Well-off" might be understood as "rich"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which one is natural among the words in the bracket.

*To seem* means "to appear to be" or "to give the impression of being" - something you think might be true, or probably might be true, but you can't prove it yet.  If this is what you mean, then use *seem*.  If something is true in fact, or able to be directly observed, *seem* should not be used.

> in the #1, I tried to make 'it' and 'the very fist few days' equal, whereas In the #2, 'it' represents 'to get over~~',did I do well?

Yep.  *It* can be used in a [provisional sense](http://www.englishgrammar.org/impersonal-pronoun/).  Also, you could be expressing an impersonal verb here, which is a situation where you are saying how things are in general without really attaching it to a specific subject.  Either use of *it* fits here and is valid.

> Here we can not remove 'the' from 'the very first few days' because it's definite time, right?

Right.  You use *the* because you are not talking about *any* "first few days" but a specific "first few days" - the *the* is also a signal that you mean *days* as a singular item and not as a plural collection of days.